# Can't add UITableView to UIView swift

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, uitableview, uiview

I have a `UIViewController` with a header subview and a `UITableView`.
My tableView with its custom cells works perfectly when I implement it on a `UITableView` class, but once I try to imbed it in my `UIViewController`, I get the tableview frame that I see based on the different background color but it doesn't get populated with my custom cell.

My print statement in tableview (...`cellForRowAtIndexPath` ..) doesn't print anything, it's as if the function is not called.

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong, any help is much appreciated!

```
import UIKit

class ProfileViewController: UIViewController , UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {

var tableView: UITableView! 
var header: UIView!
var userName: UILabel!
var userImage: UIImageView!
var dataDict : NSDictionary!
var cellArray: NSArray!
var friends = [Friends]()

init(dataDict: NSDictionary , nibName: String?, bundle: NSBundle?){
    super.init(nibName: nibName, bundle: bundle)
    self.dataDict = dataDict

}

required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    cellArray = dataDict?.objectForKey("data") as! NSArray

    tableView.delegate = self
    tableView.dataSource = self

    header   = UIView(frame: CGRectZero)
    header.backgroundColor =  UIColor( red:77/255.0, green:255/255.0, blue:195/255.0, alpha:1.0)

    userName = UILabel(frame: CGRectZero)
    userName.textAlignment = .Left
    userName.text = "Nachwa El khamlichi"
    userName.textColor = UIColor.blackColor()
    userName.frame = CGRectMake(10, 100, self.view.frame.width/2, 40)

    userImage  = UIImageView(frame: CGRectZero)
    userImage.frame = CGRectMake(10, 30, 80, 80)

    tableView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsets(top: 300, left: 0, bottom: 0, right: 0)
    tableView.backgroundColor = UIColor.orangeColor()
    tableView.separatorStyle = UITableViewCellSeparatorStyle.SingleLine

    self.view.addSubview(header)
    self.view.addSubview(userName) 
    self.view.addSubview(userImage)
    self.view.addSubview(tableView)
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

     func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

     func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

        return cellArray.count
    }

     func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        print(cellArray.count)
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier( NSStringFromClass(Cell), forIndexPath: indexPath) as! Cell

        let friendName = cellArray[indexPath.row]["name"] as? String
        let avatarId   = cellArray[indexPath.row]["id"] as? String

        friends.append(Friends(name: friendName!, avatarId: avatarId!))

        cell.friend?.name =  friendName
        cell.friend = friends[indexPath.row]
        return cell
    }

     func tableView(tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGFloat {
        return 40
    }
}
```

Comment: @Nch-just set frame for UItableview .write 
 tableView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 320, height: 568)
 in your viewDidLoad Method
Hope it will work fine for you..

Answer (score 2):

I think you forget to add

```
    tableView = UITableView(frame: UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds, style: UITableViewStyle.Plain)
    tableView.delegate      =   self
    tableView.dataSource    =   self
    tableView.registerClass(UITableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "cell")
    self.view.addSubview(self.tableView)
```

at the same time you forget to add frame

```
  header   = UIView(frame: CGRectZero)
  header.frame = CGRectMake(10, 100, self.view.frame.width/2, 40)
  header.backgroundColor =  UIColor( red:77/255.0, green:255/255.0, blue:195/255.0, alpha:1.0)
```

**OPtion-2**

if every thing is fine check once
  your `cellArray` contains data available or not`,

**option-3**

after this line add this

```
   self.view.addSubview(self.tableView)

    tableView.reloadData()
```

Comment: where you created the view on that place add this code

Comment: Thank you! when I add  tableView = UITableView(frame: UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds, style: UITableViewStyle.Plain) it crashes but with tableView = UITableView() , my tableView shows, but it's empty.  I'm using a custom cell from my Cell.swift class, I register it this way, which worked in a UITableViewController:  tableView.registerClass(Cell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: NSStringFromClass(Cell)) , which doesn't work anymore that I've imbedded it in the UIViewController. Any thoughts about this?

Comment: cellArray is not null, I can print its data, but my Cell class does not receive it somehow.

Comment: check the option -3 answer